# Having trouble getting part of an HTML line in Java with regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm trying to get a part of a line in an HTML line with a regular expression but I can't get it to work.

Here is the html (necessary) part :

```
(five random numbers)/ ">(the word I want to extract, between 2 and 45 characters)<
```

So I'm using this regex:

```
"[0-9]{5}\\/\\\"\\s\\>(\\.{1,45})\\<"
```

And I can't get it to work...

I always get a "no match found" when I try to get my word via `group()` after a `.find()` of my `Matcher`. Hope I'm clear enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
"[0-9]{5}/\"\\s>(.{1,45})<"
```

Maybe better

```
"\\d{5}/\"\\s*>([^<]{1,45})<"
```

which will also allows newline to be captured, and prevents ending with a later second `<`.

Comment: At first, it told me that there was an illegal escape character, so I added a "\" before the "\s" and it compiled, but I got the same error: "No match found"

Comment: If "with 5 random numbers" you mean _digits_, it should work. **However in the original text is a space _before_ the double quote, and in the pattern _after_ the double quote.** Maybe that?

Comment: Wow I feel dumb now, I "miswrote" it in the original text. It turns out that your regex was good, it just missed a backslash before the 's'. I also had an other error in the rest of my code. (Nothing to do with the regex but it had a lot to do with how I interpreted the results). Thank you for your help Joop!